# Ubuntu keeps freezing.  How do I Reinstall Ubuntu 12.04 

Tags: 12.04, re-installation

I have a desktop computer running the latest version of Ubuntu 12.04.  But it keeps freezing after 2-3 minutes. How can I erase the disk and reinstall? (I already saved all I needed information that I like to keep). Can I boot from a USB key? I have access to another computer for download.

Comment: Do you believe some action or steps you chose may have led to the current **Ubuntu** install becoming unstable?  Did it fail to properly install, or give an **error message**?  *Otherwise what is causing this may be unstable hardware, and/or a software compatibility issue.*

Answer (score 1):

You can boot either from the USB that you mentioned, or from CD.  To install from CD, just [Download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) Ubuntu, burn it into a CD.  Boot from CD ( make sure you system is set to boot from CD), and follow the installation steps.  When you get to the Allocate Drive Space 0r (installation Type),

[image] 
Choose Erase Disk and Install.  To use USB, you can [See this site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)